(TYPESCRIPT CHROME EXTENSION) Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule",..); gets added unintentionally in compiled JS from TS
How can I get rid of this unnecessary line which cause errors Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined.
I am creating Typescript Chrome Extension and I've been trying to fix this problem for long time now.
Compiled JavaScript
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
console.log("running");
async function cacheUserCreationDate(userRobloxCreationDate) {
}
let backgroundAPIList = new Map();
backgroundAPIList.set("CacheUserCreationDate", cacheUserCreationDate);
console.log("setting up!");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((communicationRequest) => {
    console.log("got!");
    console.log(communicationRequest.parameters);
});

TypeScript
import { UserCreationDate } from "../background-types/types";

async function cacheUserCreationDate(userCreationDate : UserxCreationDate) : Promise<void> {
    
}

let backgroundAPIList = new Map<string, (...parameters: any[]) => Promise<unknown>>()
backgroundAPIList.set("CacheUserCreationDate", cacheUserCreationDate)

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((communicationRequest: CommunicationRequest) => {
    console.log(communicationRequest.parameters)
})

tsconfig.ts

{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES2022",
"module": "CommonJS",
"rootDir": "./",
"outDir": "dist",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"alwaysStrict": true,
"skipLibCheck": true
},
"include": \["src/\*\*/\*"\],
"exclude": \["node_modules", "dist"\]
}

Building Process
"scripts": {
    "dev": "",
    "test": "",
    "clean": "IF EXIST dist rmdir /s /q dist",
    "compile": "npx tsc",
    "copy-assets": "robocopy . dist /S /E /XF tsconfig.json /XD src /XD dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile  && npm run copy-assets"
  }


It's added entirely intentionally, because your output module type is CommonJS.

No, it is not added when you don't use import statements. (No addition in content script, etc). So this is the problem.
